# How to efficienlty get all include paths in MSVC2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm tyring to refactor my code using include-what-you-use, but I need to figure out exactly which directories VS is looking in.

How do I get a listing of all include paths visible to files in my project?

If I add an incorrect include, something like "#include " I get the listing I want, but I can't copy and paste the damn thing! (and OCR doesn't seem to work).

How do I get this list?

[image]

Comment: You can, in fact, press Ctrl+C when a standard message box is shown (and this looks like one) to copy its contents.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay cool, want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes please post this, so many people are unaware Ctrl-C works in any standard dialog box and instead resort to inferior ways to get it like screenshots etc

Answer (score 1):

Copy/pasting from the dialog is ok if you want to do this once manually but doesn't scale well. Since you tagged this msbuild, here's a solution using it. Create a file names showincludes.targets and paste this msbuild code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="ShowIncludes">
    <Message Text="$(Include);%(ClCompile.AdditionalIncludeDirectories)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now to get the list of includes for any project file use

```
msbuild \path\to\vcxproj /p:ForceImportAfterCppTargets=\path\to\showincludes.targets /t:ShowIncludes
```

This will import said file into the project give, so it has access to all properties, and print out the value of the INCLUDE environment variable which is by default used by the compiler, and also the value of AdditionalIncludeDirectories which is passed to the compiler by msbuild.